# Compositeness testing using Jacobi polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Let $P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$ be [Jacobi polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials) . If $p$ is a prime number such that $\alpha , \beta$ are natural numbers and $\alpha + \beta <p$, then $$P_p^{(\alpha,\beta)}(a) \equiv a \pmod{p}$$  for all odd integers $a$ greater than one .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtijEOgCAQBHteQQkJjSE2EN9CDj0jBrwL0Ph70VjtbGbY2ckLyHyAm72I2L8FZ71Iuyy0qRNWiimwYvN15o0MaMN6eT0MkP3AS3JNV1dcKULMdxi3oJaYG_5qpcLUUkftHx-WKJA=&lang=maxima&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have tested this claim for many random values of $p$ , $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and there were no counterexamples .

Comment: Are you including $0$ in the natural numbers?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes.

Answer (score 1):

We use the identity
$$P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)=\sum_{s=0}^n \binom{n+\alpha}{n-s}\binom{n+\beta}{s}\left(\frac{x-1}2\right)^s\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)^{n-s},$$
and assume that $p\geq 3$. For $s=0$, the sum is simply $(x+1)/2$ modulo $p$ (by Fermat's little theorem), and for $s=p$, the sum is $(x-1)/2$, so those two terms sum to $x$. It suffices to show that
$$\sum_{s=1}^{p-1} \binom{p+\alpha}{p-s}\binom{p+\beta}{s}\left(\frac{x-1}2\right)^s\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)^{p-s}\equiv 0\bmod p$$
for all integer $x$. We claim, in fact, that each of these terms are multiples of $p$. By Lucas's theorem, for $0<s<p$,
$$\binom{p+\alpha}{p-s}\equiv \binom{1}{0}\binom{\alpha}{p-s}\bmod p,$$
and
$$\binom{p+\beta}{s}\equiv \binom{1}{0}\binom{\beta}{s}\bmod p.$$
However, since $\alpha+\beta<s+(p-s)$, either $\alpha<p-s$ or $\beta<s$, so one of these is $0\bmod p$.